# MassTransit won't update settings for existing Azure Service Bus queue

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

If I send a message to a specific queue, before the queue has been created, a queue will be created automatically for me.

The problem is that it leads to a kind of race condition when new messages/queues are added. If my producer service starts and produces a message before the consumer service has started, then a new queue will be created with default values. When the consumer service starts, I would have hoped that it would reconfigure the existing queue with the specific config that I want, but it does not change anything (`AutoDeleteOnIdle`, `MaxSizeInMegabytes`, etc).

Is there a recommended way to do this? :thinking: Are receive (and subscription endpoints) something that should be configured globally by all services, so that "first one wins"?

The producer service:

```
private void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollection services, string asbConnectionString)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(asbConnectionString);
        });
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
}

...

private async SendAsync() {
    var sendEndpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(IMyCommand.QueueUri);
    await sendEndpoint.Send<IMyCommand>(new MyCommand { CommandText = $"The time is {DateTimeOffset.Now}" });
}
```

The consumer service:

```
private void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollection services, string asbConnectionString)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer<MyCommandConsumer>();

        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(asbConnectionString);
        
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(IMyCommand.QueueName, configurator =>
            {
                configurator.PublishFaults = false;
                configurator.AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                configurator.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 2048;
                configurator.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

                configurator.ConfigureConsumer<MessageCommandConsumer>(context, consumerConfigurator =>
                {
                    consumerConfigurator.UseConcurrencyLimit(20);
                    consumerConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                });
            });
        });
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general guidance is that consuming services should be deployed/started before producing services. And a bus shouldn't be used until it has been started.

While some of the values can be specified as query parameters on the destination address, the only ones supported by Azure Service bus are `autodelete` and `type` (only one of those is useful to end users).

The queue description/settings aren't updated because they would change constantly if services aren't consistent.

*UPDATE: The other reason is that some deploy their topics/queues with resource manager scripts (or something like Terraform) and if MassTransit changed them it would break those deployments by removing their custom settings.*

Comment: Alright! A somewhat related question: Topic configuration. Who in your opinion should be responsible for that? The one that publishes an event or the one that consumes it? I guess what I'm thinking about is that there multiple publishers and/or consumers.

But yeah. I just saw your edit. And I guess that would make the most sense to me. Let Terraform/ARM configure/create queues and topics, and let MassTransit use them.

Comment: Well, that isn't my recommendation, but just sharing what some companies do when they have configuration with specific needs. And configuring the publish topology should be a shared concern, both producers and consumers need to know about, since it's changing the default behavior. I usually put the customizations into the _Contracts_ assembly so that it is shared across services.